# jqPlot stackSeries: true, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: charts, jqplot

I want to display 3 data series.

Whenever I set the `stackSeries: true` option in the I get the

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

or

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

when trying to display data.

When I remove the `stackSeries: true` attribue then the chart is rendered. What's wrong?

### Update

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var bar1 = [
    <?php
        if(!empty($bar1)){
            $i = 0;
            foreach($bar1 as $bar){
                $i++;
                if(!empty($bar['jobs']['date_published'])){
                    if($i == count($bar1))
                        echo '[\''.$bar['jobs']['date_published'].'\', '.$bar[0]['count'].']';
                    else
                        echo '[\''.$bar['jobs']['date_published'].'\', '.$bar[0]['count'].'], ';
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
    ];
    var bar2 = [
    <?php
        if(!empty($bar2)){
            $i = 0;
            foreach($bar2 as $bar){
                $i++;
                if(!empty($bar['jobs']['date_published'])){
                    if($i == count($bar2))
                        echo '[\''.$bar['jobs']['date_published'].'\', '.$bar[0]['count'].']';
                    else
                        echo '[\''.$bar['jobs']['date_published'].'\', '.$bar[0]['count'].'], ';
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
    ];
    var bar3 = [
    <?php
        if(!empty($bar3)){
            $i = 0;
            foreach($bar3 as $bar){
                $i++;
                if(!empty($bar['jobs']['date_published'])){
                    if($i == count($bar3))
                        echo '[\''.$bar['jobs']['date_published'].'\', '.$bar[0]['count'].']';
                    else
                        echo '[\''.$bar['jobs']['date_published'].'\', '.$bar[0]['count'].'], ';
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
    ];
    <?php   
        if(!empty($bar1) && !empty($bar2) && !empty($bar3))
            echo 'var labels = ["Bar 1", "Bar 2", "Bar 3"];';
        else if(!empty($bar1) && !empty($bar2))
            echo 'var labels = ["Bar 1", "Bar 2"];';
        else if(!empty($bar2) && !empty($bar3))
            echo 'var labels = ["Bar 2", "Bar 3"];';
        else if(!empty($bar1) && !empty($bar3))
            echo 'var labels = ["Bar 1", "Bar 3"];';
        else if(!empty($bar1))
            echo 'var labels = ["Bar 1"];';
        else if(!empty($bar2))
            echo 'var labels = ["Bar 2"];';
        else if(!empty($bar3))
            echo 'var labels = ["Bar 3"];';
    ?>
    optionsObj = {
        //stackSeries: true,
        seriesColors:[<?php if(!empty($bar1)) echo '"#4bb2c5",';
                            if(!empty($bar2)) echo '"#F78181",';
                            if(!empty($bar3)) echo '"#9AFE2E",';
                            echo '"#4bb2c5"'; ?>],
        animate:true,
        legend:{
            show:true,
            location:"sw",
            rowSpacing:"0px",
            labels:labels
        },
        title:{
            text:"Jobs",
            fontSize:"12px"                     
        },
        seriesDefaults:{
            showMarker: true,
            pointLabels: { show: true },
            renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                barWidth: 2
            }
        },
        axes:{
            xaxis:{
                pad:1,
                tickOptions:{
                    fontSize:"10px"
                },
                renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
            },
            yaxis:{autoscale: true}
        },
        highlighter: {show: true},
        grid:{drawGridlines:true}
    };
    <?php $empty = false;
            if(!empty($bar1) && !empty($bar2) && !empty($bar3)){ ?>
            $.jqplot('chart1', [bar1, bar2, bar3], optionsObj);
    <?php } else if(!empty($bar1) && !empty($bar2)){ ?>
            $.jqplot('chart1', [bar1, bar2], optionsObj);
    <?php } else if(!empty($bar2) && !empty($bar3)){ ?>
            $.jqplot('chart1', [bar2, bar3], optionsObj);
    <?php } else if(!empty($bar1) && !empty($bar3)){ ?>
            $.jqplot('chart1', [bar1, bar3], optionsObj);
    <?php } else if(!empty($bar1)){ ?>
            $.jqplot('chart1', [bar1], optionsObj);
    <?php } else if(!empty($bar2)){ ?>
            $.jqplot('chart1', [bar2], optionsObj);
    <?php } else if(!empty($bar3)){ ?>
            $.jqplot('chart1', [bar3], optionsObj);
    <?php } ?>

});
```

Comment: why is this tagged cakephp?

Comment: Its a part of a cakephp project. Maybe thats helpful.

Comment: What kind of graph are you trying to render?

Comment: part? you need to actually have a cakephp related issue here to tag this rightfully as cakephp. otherwise you can start tagging it PHP, Unix and thousand other things which all are "part" of your code at some point.

Comment: @mark silly me, I am trying to render a bar chart.

Comment: Try to put `stackSeries: true` outside of `rendererOptions`. If you want put the code...

Comment: stackSeries is working for some of the series but for some it doesnt. Is it possible that it has something to do with the values of the data points in series?

Comment: If you put your code I could help you..

Answer (score 3):

I found that if my dataset has discontinuities in it anywhere, then a stacked graph will throw an error.

For example, this data series will throw an error:

```
[
[[0,22],[1,22],[2,22]],
[[0,33],[2,33]],
]
```

this one will not:

```
[
[[0,22],[1,22],[2,22]],
[[0,33],[1,33],[2,33]],
]
```

Note the difference between the two.  The first one doesn't have a data point at X=1 for the second series.  The fix would be to make sure all your series have values at all the possible X values, setting any missing ones to zero:

```
[
[[0,22],[1,22],[2,22]],
[[0,33],[1,0],[2,33]],
]
```